# Xpath. Get text of specified tags in order of appearance on the page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get the text from h2, h3 and p tag on the page in the order they appear on html page. 
Example:
All highlighted text should be extracted in this order.
[image]

When using the following xpath:

```
response.xpath('//*[name()=("h2", "h3","p")]/text()').extract()
```

Im getting the following error:

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //*[name()=("h2", "h3","p")]/text()
```

Where am I wrong? Is there another way to reach my goal?

Comment: What exactly you want to get as output (and what you don't want if there some exception case)? Also add HTML as text, not as image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by combining a few conditionals using `or`:

```
response.xpath('//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]/text()')
```

You could also select the same thing by combining a few paths and chaining multiple `.xpath()` calls:

```
response.xpath('//h2|//h3|//p').xpath('./text()')
```

I'm not sure if there are any performance differences, but I'd just go with the one you find easier to read.
If performance is a big concern, I recommend profiling both ways.